# Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure construction on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, lebesgue-measure, borel-measures

In Athreya's "Measure Theory and Probability Theory", it introduces Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure construction on $\mathbb{R}^n$ in general in the following way:

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfy the following properties:

1. Let $(x_1,x_2)\leq (y_1,y_2)$ iff $x_1\leq y_1$ and $x_2\leq y_2$.
   If $x\leq y$ in this partial order, then $f(y_1,y_2)-f(x_1,y_2)-f(y_1,x_2)+f(x_1,x_2)\geq 0$.
2. $f$ is right-continuous for each coordinate.
3. $x\leq y\ (\forall x_n\leq y_n)\implies f(x)\leq f(y)$ (this condition is omitted but I think this might be needed).

Then $\mu((x_1,x_2]\times (y_1,y_2])=f(y_1,y_2)-f(x_1,y_2)-f(y_1,x_2)+f(x_1,x_2)$ defines a locally finite Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Conversely, any locally finite Borel measure is generated by such a function.

I have some questions about this construction:

1. I want to see a complete proof of this construction in $\mathbb{R}^n$; the first condition can be defined analogously in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Even in the book, there was no complete proof of this general construction. I am also not sure whether the third condition can be omitted or not.
2. I wonder if there is a one-to-one correspondence between such functions and locally finite Borel measures on $\mathbb{R}^n$.
   In one-dimensional case, a locally finite Borel measure corresponds to a right-continuous increasing function up to a constant. It seems like such a correspondence result, if it exists, should be more constrictive; $f(x,y)=x+y$ yields the zero measure, but any $f(x,y)=F(x)+G(y)$ does so as well.

Any reference or complete construction would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Ramiro It meant the partial order in 1. I have added it in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}$Concerning your question 1: A complete proof of this result (based on a discrete approximation) can be found, for instance, in [Kallenberg's book "Foundations of Modern Probability"](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387953137), where it is given as Corollary 3.26. Another kind of arguments, using e.g. semirings, can be found e.g. in Example 1.54 in [Probability Theory, A Comprehensive Course, by Klenke](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781447153610), where the Lebesgue measure over $\R^d$ is constructed; the construction of the Lebesgue–Stieltjes measure is quite similar.

Concerning your question 2: Clearly, if $\mu_f$ denotes the Lebesgue–Stieltjes measure for a right-continuous function $f\colon\R^d\to\R$ with nonnegative increments (in the natural sense, as defined e.g. in Kallenberg's book), and if $g\colon\R^d\to\R$ is such that
\begin{equation}
\label{star}
\tag{$*$}
g(x_1,\dotsc,x_d)=f(x_1,\dotsc,x_d)+\sum_{j=1}^d h_j(x_1,\dotsc,x_{j-1},x_{j+1},\dotsc,x_d)
\end{equation}
for some functions $h_j\colon\R^{d-1}\to\R$ and all $(x_1,\dotsc,x_d)\in\R^d$, then $\mu_g=\mu_f$.
Vice versa, if $\mu_g=\mu_f$, then the (appropriate $d$-fold) increments of $g-f$ are identically zero, which implies \eqref{star}.

Comment: Is converse of this " Every measure $\mu$ on $\Bbb R^{d}$ which is finite on every compact subset is Lebesgue -Stieltjes measure. is true?